Spark lazy val evaluates twice for dataframe
I have a lazy val defined in my code studentDataReader which eventually reads data from an S3 path. My understanding is that even if I call this multiple times, it should call S3 once only.

The compiler does not immediately evaluate the bound expression of a lazy val. It evaluates the variable only on its first access.
Upon initial access, the compiler evaluates the expression and stores the result in the lazy val. Whenever we access this val at a later stage, no execution happens, and the compiler returns the result. Source: https://www.baeldung.com/scala/lazy-val

However, that is not happening. And every invokation does an execution i.e. makes a call to S3 to read again. (confirmed from Spark UI)
Below is a skeleton code. (Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.11)
The Reader used is a custom trait not defined below for simplicity:
trait CommonProcessor {
  val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.getActiveSession.get
  import spark.implicits._

  lazy val studentDataReader: Reader[Setting, DataFrame] =
    Reader({config =>
      getStudentData(config)
    })

  def getStudentData(setting: Setting): DataFrame = {
    val studentData = getInput(setting, deltaPathToS3) //Behind the scenes calls spark.read.format("delta")
    studentData.cache
  }
}


trait StudentDataProcessor { self: CommonProcessor =>

  import spark.implicits._

  lazy val getResult: Reader[Setting, DataFrame] = {
    for {
      df <- getFinalData
    } yield {
      dropDuplicates(df)
    }
  }

  lazy val getFinalData: Reader[Setting, DataFrame] = {

    for {
      studentData <- studentDataReader
      studentTeacherData <- studentTeacherDataReader
    } yield {
      doSomeProcess(studentData, studentTeacherData)
    }
  }

  lazy val studentTeacherDataReader: Reader[Setting, DataFrame] = {
    for {
      s <- studentDataReader
      f <- teacherDataReader
    } yield {
      mergeData(s, f)
    }
  }
}

object StudentData extends StudentDataProcessor with CommonProcessor {
  def process(setting: Setting) := {

    try {
      val result = getResult.run(setting)
    }
  }
}

StudentData.process(setting)

As you can see, I am making 2 calls.
studentData <- studentDataReader and s <- studentDataReader. In each call, spark is reading from S3.
What can I do here to have studentDataReader return a cached result instead of going through whole execution everytime.

Spark is "lazy" itself in the sense that a Dataframe is the description of a computation but it's not necessarily yet materialised. And using twice the same DF will materialize it twice unless you use cache or something like that. I'm not sure what is Reader in your code but sounds like it may be preventing you to do that though because it's encapsulating the DF. I would do val cached = getStudentData().cache and work with this cached twice or more.

@GaëlJ Doing getStudentData(config).cache within studentDataReader does not help it. If that is what you are suggesting

What I was saying was more "what is Reader?", can you work without it?

Follows the Saprk paradigm afaics.

if you are doing schema inference of a CSV file, that starts with a full scan of the data to infer the schema. Even if there's some sampling going on, it is still a full read

because DataFrame is a description of the data,not the data itself
